# Nvidia display driver

Tags: nvidia, software-installation

I have recently installed Ubuntu as a duel boot with Windows 7,
I have already installed Nvidia driver software in Windows,
my questions are that
"Should seperate driver software be installed in Ubuntu for Nvidia Graphic card?"
"How does Ubuntu use this Nvidia Graphic card ?"

Comment: Yes, all os installations will require a "separate" nvidia driver. In Ubuntu, it will be used the same way as any other driver.

Comment: @mikewhatever What are the applications of Graphic card in Ubuntu ? Can we play high graphic games in Ubuntu ? Or is it just for display sake?

Comment: You can do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Dude !!   you do.
Follow [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) for installing the driver for your graphics card.

Also, You need to download the Linux version of the games which you play on windows.

If you are talking about some old PC games like counter strike which supported [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL), you can either:

1. Run their windows version using [wine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29). wine can installed by simply

   $ sudo apt-get install wine

   run the windows installer directly by installing wine.
2. Find your game on [steam](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with Nvidia graphics card drivers, you dont have to install it manually.

1. Open dash by clicking windows key
2. search `Additional drivers` and open it (you have to wait for few seconds for it to load)
3. then select the nvidia driver listed in it

*installing/upgrading nvidia drivers for novice users is not recommended because you might end up with system not bootable*

(see the following screenshot, I have already selected the nvidia drivers)
[image]